# C++ which container "a la map" to store different objet

Tags: c++

- I have to type of very complex object A and B in 2 vectors:

  ```
  vector<A> va;
  vector<B> vb
  ```
- I want to loop over `va` and `vb`, and store pairs in a C++ container:

  ```
  for(i:va)
    for(j:vb)
      container[i]=[j]
  ```
- notice that the container can have several time the same "key" object.
- I wanted to use a multimap but `A` and `B` are very complex compound data type and I do not want to slim information when setting the "key".
- My final goal is to be able to access information for `i` and its corresponding `j` in the container.
- Do you know which container is suitable for this task?

Comment: You *could* store pairs of iterators in the multimap.. Assuming the vectors aren't updated after some point in time, and the iterators aren't invalidated.

Comment: It is not clear what 'slim information when setting the "key"' means. Could you rephrase that?

Comment: What about a multimap containing pointers to elements in `va` and `vb`?

Comment: StoryTeller: your solution seem complicate

Comment: Beta: I mean that I want to be able to keep all the information of the object.

Comment: Tristan: your idea is quite interesting. I'll try this and see.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.